# Redux-toolkit state is not updated

Tags: reactjs, state, redux-toolkit

I am creating a login and in the **.then** function, setting the state of user.
The data is set correctly but after redirect (through code) to the next page, I could not access the new state using **useSelector** function.

Login.js

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    async function getUser(){
      return await login(username, password);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    getUser()
    .then((userObj) => {
      if(userObj.user._id !== undefined){
        dispatch(setAuthUser(userObj.user));
        message.current.innerHTML = '';
        window.location = `/Shops/Near/`;
        history.push('/Shops/Near/');
      }
      else{
        message.current.innerHTML = 'Invalid username or password, try again!';
      }
    });
  }, [username, password]);
```

Shops.js

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Shops = () => {
  const [shops, setShops] = useState([]);
  const [isPreferedPage, setIsPreferedPage] = useState(false);
  const message = useRef(null);
  const user = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state.user);
    return state.user;
  }); //bug
```

userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
};

export const user = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuthUser: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
```

I want to know what is the problem, I tried to remove the async call and even set the state in empty call but still it never been updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do `state =` as that would not modify *the object in `state`*, but throw the object in `state` away and put a new one into the variable.

`state.foo =` would be okay, `state =`  is not.

Do `return action.payload` instead.

See also https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, return 
`action.payload`  does not work.
Also use 
`state.foo = `
and define it in the **initialeState** does not work.

Comment: You will also need to dispatch your action, so not call `setAuthUser(user)`, but `dispatch(setAuthUser(user))` - you did not share that code, so I could not comment on that.

Comment: `const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    async function getUser(){
      return await login(username, password);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    getUser()
    .then((userObj) => {
      if(userObj.user._id !== undefined){
        dispatch(setAuthUser(userObj.user));
        message.current.innerHTML = '';
        window.location = `/Shops/Near/`;
        history.push('/Shops/Near/');
      }
      else{
        message.current.innerHTML = 'Invalid username or password, try again!';
      }
    });
  }, [username, password]);
`
I used it like that :(

Comment: Coule `userObj.user` there just be `undefined`? Are you using the Redux Devtools Browser extension? What do you see there?

Comment: No, it has a valid value and the dispatch if fired, plus the payload has the correct values.
I am not expert in Redux DevTools ext.

Comment: Does the state change there, too?

Comment: when debugging it seems that the state is changed but once redirect to the next page and when  dispatch the useSelector it returns the default value

Comment: in Redux DevTools, it does not change while calling the reducer.

Comment: I note that if I stopped the redirect to the new page, the new values of the state appears in the Redux DevTools.